# Cannot find module in Angular2 typescript class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a typescript file with the following content:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BookService } from "../../services/book.service";
import { Book } from "../../Models/book";


@Component({
    selector: 'app-book-list',
    templateUrl: './book-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./book-list.component.css']
})
export class BookListComponent implements OnInit {


    books: Book[];

    constructor(private bookService: BookService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.bookService.getBooks()
            .subscribe(books => this.books = books);
    }
}
```

When I compile, it is complaining that it doesn't know where the Book.cs file is.

Here's the error:

> (TS) Cannot find Module '../../Models/Book'

However, when I was constructing this path, I constructed it through the visual studio intellisence. So, it damn well knows where it is.

Here's my project structure:

[image]

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have another file named `Book` with a different extension in the same folder?

Comment: Not at all. I have book.service.ts which under services folder.

Comment: And I suppose you are properly exporting the module in `Book.cs` ?

Comment: You can't combine c# and typescript. Typescript = is transpiled into javascript and this is executed in the web browser. c# = is compiled into an executable or library and is executed by the web server (like IIS) or by the O/S.

Comment: I was just following this tutorial and this guy did it like that. He used the Vehicle.cs class inside the typescript class. Here's the link: https://github.com/mosh-hamedani/vega/commit/b3294762badadd00c7424abc7cae0942f0f3a5b4

Comment: @bangbang - I do not see a `vehicle.cs` file or a reference to such a file in this repository.

Comment: The repository though illustrates how web api works together with angular. You can call the web api service(s) from angular but you can't mix code files between c# and typescript and none of the code in the repository does this.

Comment: And I am not saying that this is a recommendation or a guideline. I am stating that it is technically not possible which is why you should not try to do it.

Comment: Here is the vehicle.cs class: https://github.com/mosh-hamedani/vega/blob/master/Core/Models/Vehicle.cs. I do understand what you are saying, but I just want to know why the author used the cs file in the ts code knowing well tht it wont work. Did you see where he used it? 
Check this: https://github.com/mosh-hamedani/vega/blob/b3294762badadd00c7424abc7cae0942f0f3a5b4/ClientApp/app/components/vehicle-list/vehicle-list.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the comments*

> Here is the vehicle.cs class: github.com/mosh-hamedani/vega/blob/master/Core/Models/…. I do understand what you are saying, but I just want to know why the author used the cs file in the ts code knowing well tht it wont work. Did you see where he used it? Check this: github.com/mosh-hamedani/vega/blob/…

You are looking at 2 different files. [/ClientApp/app/models/vehicle.ts](https://github.com/mosh-hamedani/vega/blob/b3294762badadd00c7424abc7cae0942f0f3a5b4/ClientApp/app/models/vehicle.ts) and [/Core/Models/Vehicle.cs](https://github.com/mosh-hamedani/vega/blob/master/Core/Models/Vehicle.cs). You can check the links you posted in your comment to see for yourself. That is why this application transpiles/works, because it is pointing to a `.ts` file and not a `.cs` file which happens to have the same name (but not extension or location for that matter).

Chalk this one up to one of those mistakes that you make when you have been looking at something for too long, it happens to the best of us.

Comment: Wow! Amazing! Thank you for opening my eyes. You are right, I spent too much time on this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the file itself exists, but it has a `.cs` extension, meaning that it's a C# file. The TypeScript compiler looks only for `.ts` and `.d.ts` files when searching in the specified directories.

You should rename the file `Book.ts` and use TypeScript to define (from what I infer) the model